# Is there any way of deleting EC2 instances by tags using TerraForm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, destroy, terraform

Is there any way of deleting EC2 instances of only specific ec2 tags using TerraForm?

I need to delete several instances of specific tags at once

Comment: What's the use case? Terraform is used to manage immutable infrastructure, your idea conflicts the design.

Comment: If the ec2 instances weren't created using terraform in the first place, that probably isn't a good idea. You could use a 1 or 2 line bash + cli script to do this though.